# C program calling malloc results in bus error?

Tags: c, malloc, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have written this code to declare a pointer, `p`, and then dynamically allocate 4 bytes of memory for type int to then store some data in it. `p` should point to an address which holds the data `6` of type int. The program should then print out the data from the pointer variable using the `dereferencing operator`. I have also included the `free()` function to release allocated memory from the heap. I don't understand why I'm receiving a bus error. The same code has been executed by a peer and it has worked perfectly fine. I'm using a Mac M2 and running the code on `vscode`. What could be causing this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int *a){
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main(){
    int *p;
    foo(p);
    *p = 6;
    printf("%d",*p);
    free(p);
    return(0);
}
```

Here's the error message: `zsh: bus error`

Note that if I were to remove the `foo()` function and replace the calling line with `p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` then the program works perfectly fine. Why is it that having it in the previous method results in a bus error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C arguments are passed to functions by value. It means relative to your program that the function `foo` deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `p` declared in `main`.

So any changes of the copy within the function leave the original pointer unchanged.

You may imagine the function and its call the following way

```
foo(p);

//...

void foo( /*int *a */ ){
    int *a = p;
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

As you can see it is the local variable `a` declared within the function that was changed. The original pointer `p` stays unchanged. Function parameters are local variables of the function.

So as the pointer `p` stays unchanged and is not initialized then dereferencing the pointer like for example

```
*p = 6;
```

results in the bus error.

To change an object (including a pointer) within a function you need to pass it by reference.

In C *passing by reference* means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the passed pointer you get a direct access to the object pointed to by the pointer and can change it.

So your program should look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo( int **a )
{
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main( void )
{
    int *p;

    foo( &p );

    if ( p != NULL )
    { 
        *p = 6;
        printf( "%d\n", *p );
    }

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to two aspects.

The first one is that the function `main` without parameters shall be declared as

```
int main( void )
```

And the second one is that in C (opposite to C++) you need not to cast the pointer returned from the function `malloc`. That is you may write

```
*a = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

And also you should check whether the pointer `p` changed within the function is not a null pointer before dereferencing it in `main`.  On the other hand, the function `free`  may be called for a null pointer.

Answer (score 4):

In your function `foo` the argument `a` is a local variable. You are assigning the result of `malloc` to that, but this has no effect on the program outside of this function call.

As it stands, you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, resulting in undefined behavior. You also have a (in this case short-lived) memory leak if `malloc` succeeds, because you cannot free this memory later.

To accomplish this you need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
void foo(int **a) {
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main(void) {
    int *p;
    foo(&p);
    *p = 6;
    printf("%d", *p);
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

You probably also want to get into the habit of checking that `malloc` succeeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are changing the value of the pointer, you need to pass the address of the pointer. Otherwise, you simply have a copy of the address.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int **a){
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main(){
    int *p;
    foo(&p);
    *p = 6;
    printf("%d",*p); // 6
    free(p);
    return(0);
}
```